# What is the most classic keyboard shortcut for switching between input sources (languages)?

Tags: keyboard, input-source

What is the most classic/used keyboard shortcut for switching between input sources (languages)?
Except for <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> of course which is used by Spotlight.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your shortcut don't interfere with spotlight you can use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> or something else.

but as you said <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> is really good as myself use this and replace <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for spotlight, and use <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> for QuickSilver.

Comment: shift + option cannot be used.

Answer (score 0):

I use <kbd>option</kbd>